# passing a byte[] between activities app crashes but passing same byte[] between fragments it works well

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity

I have an image and I want to show this image on a fragment of another activity. I'm passing a byte[] between activities app crashes but passing the same byte[] between fragments it works well and all errors in logcat get erased.

I'm using this code in Activity1

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putByteArray("imgByte", imgByte);
    bundle.putString("ItemID", ItemID);
    bundle.putString("ShopID", ShopID);
    bundle.putString("odertime", ordertiming);
    bundle.putString("cat_name", "show_offer_details");

    intent.putExtras(bundle);


    startActivity(intent);
```

and to get this Intent in Activity2 and i have a fragment  in Activity2 where I want to show this byte[]

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {

        cat_name = bundle.getString("cat_name");
        imgByte = bundle.getByteArray("imgByte");
        ShopID = bundle.getString("ShopID");
        ItemID = bundle.getString("ItemID");
        ordertiming = bundle.getString("ordertiming");
        bundle.clear();

    }
```

and to passing in the fragment of Activity2 I'm using this code

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        details details = new details ();


        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putByteArray("imgByte", imgByte);
        args.putString("ItemID", ItemID);
        args.putString("ShopID", ShopID);
        args.putString("odertime", ordertiming);

        details .setArguments(args);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.cat_container, details , "details ");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but its crashing and all errors get erased in logcat.

while I'm passing the same byte[] within two fragments it is working properly.

is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: Instead of passing image as byte[], pass location of image

Comment: so first I need to save that image in phone memory?

Comment: That depends based on your requirements. From where you get the image? If from remote, then pass the *url*

Comment: it is from the server but I don't want to download it again it takes time to load. I want to show it as activity opens

Comment: show your logcat

Comment: that's the problem @umag when app crash  all error got erased in logcat and app restarts

Comment: Probably it's a **OutOfMemory** or **TransactionTooLargeException** as `Bundle` has size limitation **up to 1MB** when encapsulated inside `Intent`

Comment: yup that's what I think but there is no error while passing this same byte[] within fragments, why so?

Comment: You should use some good image loader library like **Glide** or **Picasso** with caching mechanism.

Comment: i'm usuing this  viewHolder.NBY_image_rcw.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bmap = viewHolder.NBY_image_rcw.getDrawingCache();
                    byte[] imgByte = BitMapTobyte(bmap);

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between two fragments occurs purely within your own process.

Passing data via `Intent` extras (or other pieces of an `Intent`) between two activities involves multiple process:

- There is an inter-process communication (IPC) call from your process to a core OS process
- There is an IPC call from that core OS process back to your process

Because of this, there are size limitations on the `Intent`. Do not pass large things between activities via an `Intent`. Instead, either:

- Use fragments, or
- Use a singleton repository that offers a cache, so that you can pass an identifier between the activities and the second activity can retrieve the data from the cache

Comment: i'm using  viewHolder.NBY_image_rcw.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bmap = viewHolder.NBY_image_rcw.getDrawingCache();
                    byte[] imgByte = BitMapTobyte(bmap); then passing it into another activity

Comment: @sam: Either use fragments or have a singleton repository cache that bitmap.

Comment: is there any other way to pass the bitmap

Comment: @sam: As I said (twice), either use fragments or use a singleton that can (carefully!) cache the bitmap. Or, as was suggested in comments, use an image loader with a cache (Glide, Picasso) for obtaining your image from the server, then pass the URL for that image between activities. Or, write the image to disk and pass a path between activities.